# is it possible to run application in particular processor?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to assign a processor to application. I have a quad core processor. I want to run a application in processor 1 for example. 1. is it possible? 2. Is there any advantage in doing this?

Answer (score 6):

It *is* possible to assign a process to one or more specific processors. It's done in Task Manager. Right-click on the process and select "Set Affinity..."

[image]

In the following dialog, select which processor(s) you want to assign the process to:

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it, I was about to post the exact same answer! Nicely done, you're quick ;)

Comment: To answer the part about whether it's worthwhile: generally, no. Windows does a pretty good job at balancing things out on its own, and if an application is capable of taking advantage of multiple cores, then limiting it to just one core will degrade its performance. This is especially true with software such as video editing, rendering, and some video games. But you _can_ do it if you feel inclined.

Comment: I was going to add that *theoretically*, system performance could be optimized by assigning processor affinity. However, if you look at the sheer number of processes running in Windows 7, it should be quickly be apparent that you just don't have *that* much control. So +1 for nhinkle for the clarification.

Comment: **NB** this setting is inherited by child processes, so if you set (for example) Explorer's affinity everything you launch in your session will also be limited to the same subset of processors.

Comment: It's still useful to be able to do. For instance if a process were allowed its own core to run it could run in (near) real-time without those 70 windows utilities constantly interrupting it for a time slice. Also, processor intensive applications (like VMs) can be isolated to their own core so you can use them without bringing your computer to a crawl. For applications that handle a large amount of data in flux, isolating to a processor (and potentially still utilizing multiple cores) will cut down on cache swapping.